# Jmeter Response Data dissapears in the "View Results Tree" Panel After Re-Opening The .jmx File

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, recording

I am using Apache JMeter 5.4.1 to record a manual test script (to be automated later) on a web application.

I need the response data logs which are recorded in the View Results Tree for debugging purposes.

I don't want to run the script before debugging, because I need to parameterize the dynamic data which changes every run thus, I need to capture them using the response data.

The problem is, I need to save the file and continue later sometimes, and when I open the file and load the .jtl file into the View Results Tree, the response data doesn't show up. Like it never existed. I can still see the results but when I click on them I see "No Data".

What causes this strange phenomenon, and how can I work around this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default JMeter doesn't save response data, if you're using [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener in GUI mode you need to additionally instruct it to save the results as XML and explicitly tell it to store response data, example setup:

[image]

If you're running the test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) - amend [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) in *user.properties* file to look like:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
```

More information: [How to Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter)